# Searching questions in Qualtrics Library with tags

Tags: search, qualtrics

I am planning to create a lot (re: hundreds) of questions in Qualtrics. I then plan to pull from those questions to create several surveys. I noticed the "Search library" option in "import question" when creating a survey does now allow you to search among questions (only search names of libraries). Is there a way to search among questions to pull into a survey, or attach tags to a question that can then be used to pull questions into a survey.

For example, you can embed HTML tags in a question. Is it possible to use those tags to pull up specific questions that I have tagged.

Thank you!